# Why is React ESLint saying I must use "this" in this particular method?

Tags: reactjs, this, eslint

Why is this suggested by ESLint?
The `Component` does not even have this `padding` or `margin` as class fields.

[image: slint]

Comment: Did you read https://eslint.org/docs/rules/class-methods-use-this? It's telling you `getListStyle` doesn't use `this` because... `getListStyle` *doesn't* use `this`.

Comment: Your right the docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the docs for the eslint rule [class-methods-use-this](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/class-methods-use-this).

> If a class method does not use `this`, it can sometimes be made into a static function.

If you convert yout method into a static one, the warning will go away.

```
static _getListStyle() {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: thanks only problem is the caller must also be static if inside the class

Comment: You need to call static functions from instance methods like this `ClassName.staticMethod()` (sadly `this.staticMethod()` or `base.staticMethod()` doesn't work in JS). `this.anotherStaticMethod()` will work from a static method and the linter shouldn't complain.